# Does not work Regex for multiple string split in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split string with multiple string delimiter.
For example :

String is **"abc[11]xyz[86]pqr[87]sdv[11]adf[86]fgr[87]fadggthy"**
Output : 
abc
xyz
pqr
sdv
adf
fgr
fadggthy

I want to split string by "[11]" , "[86]" , "[87]"
Tried following code but does not work.

```
void testSplit() {
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("abc[11]xyz[86]pqr[87]sdv[11]adf[86]fgr[87]fadggthy");
    Map<String, String> replaceStringMap = new HashMap();
    replaceStringMap.put("\\\\[11\\\\]", "11");
    replaceStringMap.put("\\\\[86\\\\]", "86");
    replaceStringMap.put("\\\\[87\\\\]", "87");
    String starter = "(";
    String middle = ")|(";
    String end = ")";
    Set<String> keySet = replaceStringMap.keySet();
    boolean isFirst = true;
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder(starter);
    Iterator<String> itr = keySet.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        String string = itr.next();
        if(itr.hasNext()) {
            regex.append(string);
            regex.append(middle);
        } else {
            regex.append(string);
            regex.append(end);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(regex.toString());
    String[] strings = message.toString().split(regex.toString());
    for(String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
   (\\[87\\])|(\\[11\\])|(\\[86\\])
   abc[11]xyz[86]pqr[87]sdv[11]adf[86]fgr[87]fadggthy
   Output:abc[11]xyz[86]pqr[87]sdv[11]adf[86]fgr[87]fadggthy
```

Expected Output:

abc
xyz
pqr
sdv
adf
fgr
fadggthy

Below Code works :

```
String regex = "(\\[87\\])|(\\[11\\])|(\\[86\\])";
```

Here if i hardcode regex then it works but when i generate regex dynamically by reading value from map then it does not work.
Problem is that i can't generate regex at dynamic level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra pair of `\` in your delimeters.

Given this:

```
    StringBuilder message = new  StringBuilder("abc[11]xyz[86]pqr[87]sdv[11]adf[86]fgr[87]fadggthy");
    Map<String, String> replaceStringMap = new HashMap();
    replaceStringMap.put("\\[11\\]", "11");
    replaceStringMap.put("\\[86\\]", "86");
    replaceStringMap.put("\\[87\\]", "87");
    String starter = "(";
    String middle = ")|(";
    String end = ")";
    Set<String> keySet = replaceStringMap.keySet();
    boolean isFirst = true;
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder(starter);
    Iterator<String> itr = keySet.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String string = itr.next();
        if (itr.hasNext()) {
            regex.append(string);
            regex.append(middle);
        } else {
            regex.append(string);
            regex.append(end);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(regex.toString());
    String[] strings = message.toString().split(regex.toString());
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

It yields this:

```
(\[86\])|(\[87\])|(\[11\])
abc
xyz
pqr
sdv
adf
fgr
fadggthy
```

Comment: Thanks @npinti. but when i print regex then it shows (\[11\])|(\[86\])|(\[87\]) so why this happen?

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya: `(\[86\])|(\[87\])|(\[11\])` is the resulting expression since in Java, to escape a \ you need to add another one, thus, \\ will be resolved as \.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution, for any value between [] considered as separator:

```
String test = abc[11]xyz[86]pqr[87]sdv[11]adf[86]fgr[87]fadggthy
String r = "(\\[[^\\]]*\\])"
for(String part : test.split(r)) println(part)

> abc
> xyz
> pqr
> sdv
> adf
> fgr
> fadggthy
```